# Problema constraint 150 "Foreign Key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql

Estoy realizando una creación de tablas en `SQL` y a la hora de ejecutar:

```
create table discos_compactos  ( 
   id_disco_compacto int, 
   titulo_cd varchar(60) not null, 
   id_disquera int not null, 
   constraint pk_discos_compactos primary key (id_disco_compacto), 
   constraint fk_id_disquera foreign key (id_disquera) references disqueras_cd
);
```

Aparece el error

> Foreign Key constraint is incorrectly formed

El ejemplo lo tome de un libro, pero creamos dos tablas antes:

```
CREATE TABLE TIPOS_MUSICA( 
  ID_TIPO INT,
  NOMBRE_TIPO VARCHAR(20 NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT UN_NOMBRE_TIPO UNIQUE (NOMBRE_TIPO),
  CONSTRAINT PK_TIPOS_MUSICA PRIMARY KEY (ID_TIPO) 
);
```

y

```
CREATE TABLE DISQUERAS_CD ( 
  ID_DISQUERA INT, 
  NOMBRE_COMPAÑIA VARCHAR(60) DEFAULT 
  'Independiente' NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_DISQUERAS_CD PRIMARY KEY (ID_DISQUERA) 
);
```

¿Que podría estar mal en el código?, lo he colocado como aparece en el ejemplo...

Comment: Falta un paréntesis en `NOMBRE_TIPO VARCHAR(20 NOT NULL,`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que si estás en un entorno Unix, tu problema podría ser que el nombre de la tabla está en mayúscula y la 'foreign key' hace referencia al nombre en minúscula.

Si el servicio MySQL está en Windows, este no es tu problma.

Hecha un vistazo a [Identifier Case Sensitivity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html).

No lo he encontrado en español, pero básicamente dice que en MySQL, las bases de datos se corresponden con directorios y las tablas con, al menos, un fichero, por lo que la sensibilidad mayúsculas-minúscula del sistema operativo, determina el comportamiento de la base de datos en este aspecto.

Answer (score 6):

Yo tuve el mismo error, causado porque las nuevas tablas se estaban creando con un cotejamiento incorrecto y un motor de almacenamiento distinto al del resto de la base de datos.

Se solucionó cambiando el cotejamiento de las nuevas tablas al correcto (de latin_swedish a utf8)y el motor de almacenamiento (MyISAM) al del resto de la base de datos (innoDB).

Puede hacerse cómodamente desde la interface de phpMyAdmin. Acabo de solucionarlo así que aún no doy con la razón de por qué éstos atributos se estaban cargando distintos a los del resto de la BD.

Comment: Me salvaste la tarde y noche.... ZZZZzzzz... Gracias

Answer (score 5):

hola y buenas yo tuve el mismo problema y nada de lo que dice aquí me funciono ya que me di cuenta que tenia la misma longitud de los valores entre la foranea y la principal eran prácticamente gemelas en ese sentido, y entonces hice lo siguiente...

**[TABLA1]: esta es la tabla principal a la que quería referenciar...**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**[TABLA2]:Esta es la tabla que contiene la foranea para referenciar a la tabla1**
[image: Esta es la tabla que contiene la foranea para referenciar a la tabla1]

lo que no me dejaba hacer la foranea con la tabla 1 era lo siguiente:

tenia los caracteres distintos cuando los modifique ya se fue el error. ojala y les sirva a muchos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto funcionó para mi!

Comment: Yo no soy DBA así que con DB voy justo, y tenia el problema de que no me dejaba crear tampoco la FK y era el puto charset, fenomenal tio..GRANDE!!

Comment: ALTER TABLE 'tabla1'
CHANGE COLUMN 'columna' VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET 'latin1';

ALTER TABLE 'tabla2'
CHANGE COLUMN 'columna' VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET 'latin1';

Answer (score 2):

El fallo reside en que te falta indicar la columna a la que se referencia la FK en la tabla foránea. Se haría así:

```
create table discos_compactos ( id_disco_compacto int, titulo_cd 
varchar(60) not null, id_disquera int not null, constraint 
pk_discos_compactos primary key 
(id_disco_compacto), constraint fk_id_disquera foreign key (id_disquera) 
references disqueras_cd(ID_DISQUERA));
```

Comment: Me ha servido perfecto, gracias por el dato!

Comment: Perfecto! Puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta y emitir algun voto para futuros usuarios que puedan tener el mismo problema. Un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

La tabla tiene que tener un índice en la columna `id_disquera` para poder usarla en una llave foránea.

La creación de tu tabla `discos_compactos` quedaría:

```
CREATE TABLE discos_compactos (
  `id_disco_compacto` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `titulo_cd` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `id_disquera` int(11) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE discos_compactos
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_disco_compacto`),
  ADD KEY `k_id_disquera` (`id_disquera`);

ALTER TABLE discos_compactos
  ADD CONSTRAINT `discos_compactos_ibfk_1` 
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_disquera`) REFERENCES DISQUERAS_CD (`ID_DISQUERA`);
```

Comment: Podría ser otra forma, gracias por el dato compañero.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder crear una `foreing key`, debes agregar antes un indice y validad que el campo tenga el mismo formato al que vas agregar, si es int(10) debe la `foreign` ser la misma. si tiene campos como `unsigned` o `zerofill` también, en tu caso no le agregaste el campo de la tabla referenciada.

```
create table discos_compactos  ( 
   id_disco_compacto int, 
   titulo_cd varchar(60) not null, 
   id_disquera int not null, 
   primary key (id_disco_compacto), 
   INDEX fk_id_disquera (id_disquera),
   constraint fk_id_disquera foreign key (id_disquera) REFERENCES DISQUERAS_CD(id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tuve el mismo problema. Después de muchas horas de experimentar, descubrí que el problema era: una tabla era MYISAM y la otra tabla era INNODB.

Los configuré a ambos en MYISAM, y me permitió configurar las restricciones