# Problema 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql

**Este es el código que utilicé. Sin embargo no me funciona, revise la sintaxis de las foreing keys y esta bien supongo, si alguien me podria ayudar se lo agredezco**

```
CREATE TABLE tiertable (
  abrev VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  nom_comp VARCHAR(20),
  descripción VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (abrev)
);

CREATE TABLE pokemon (
  nom_pokemon VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  id_pokedex INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
  vida_base INT NOT NULL,
  atk_base INT NOT NULL,
  def_base INT NOT NULL,
  atk_sp_base INT NOT NULL,
  def_sp_base INT NOT NULL,
  vel_base INT NOT NULL,
  suma_de_base INT NOT NULL,
  abrev_tier VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (abrev_tier) REFERENCES tiertable(abrev),
  -- Clasificación.     fk
  PRIMARY KEY (nom_pokemon, id_pokedex)
);
```

Comment: Brooo, ya tienes datos en las tablas ?. Yo acabe de copiar y pegar lo que pusiste y no me da error, asi que la sintaxis no es. Ahora como reproduces ese error ?

Comment: La sintaxis está bien como dicen arriba, puede ser problema del DBMS que estás usando, ¿cuál es?

Comment: ¿Te sirven algunas de [estas respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/54380/80870)? También verifica que la BD y sus tablas estén en InnoDB y no MyISAM. Verificar que `abrev` sea UNIQUE.

Comment: Sí que funciona: https://dbfiddle.uk/1dti8o-p